# 英語が残っている：xxx days, yyy consective

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

アカウント情報の所です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記の翻訳はすぐ適用します：

> $DaysVisitedTotal$ 日、$DaysVisitedConsecutive$ 日連続

[Transifex上](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/41580072?q=consecutive)のストリングはコチラです。